# Bash wildcard not working for substring match

Tags: bash

Not sure why this isnt working:

```
declare -a brands=(
"sassandbide"
"cocoandlola"
)

var="sassandbide.com"

for assigned in "${!brands[@]}"
do
    chosen_brand=${brands[$assigned]}
    echo "$chosen_brand"
    echo "$var"
    if [[ "$chosen_brand" = *$var* ]];
        then
            echo "working"
        else
            echo "not working"
    fi

done
```

Output:
sassandbide

sassandbide.com

not working

cocoandlola

sassandbide.com

not working

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: `if [[ $chosen_brand =~ $var ]]` is what you want. See [man bash](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) under the **[[ expression ]]** heading (4th paragraph). And to be completely correct you want `var="sassandbide[.]com"` to prevent `'.'` from being interpreted as matching *any character*.

Comment: still doesnt pick up the substring. cheers though

Comment: I see the issue, the comparison was backwards `if [[ $var =~ $chosen_brand ]]` - now give it a go (same end note on `var` with `"[.]"`)

Answer (score 0):

Swap `$chosen_brand` and `= *$var*` to `$var = *$chosen_brand*`.